# How to draw a rectangle with rounded corners using OpenGL|ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, rectangles

I wanted to draw a rectangle with rounded corners in OpenGL|ES.

The user will input 3 things:

1. Coordinates of top left corner (X1,Y1).
2. Coordinates of bottom right corner (X2,Y2).
3. radius for the roundness of the corner (r).

The approach I am currently taking is that I will draw 3 rectangles based on the input given by the user and then will draw four arcs on each of the four corners of the rectangle.

is it the right way of doing it or is there some better approach for this ?